# 0 to 1 relationship in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Using EF6 Database First, I'm trying to add an association for an entity. The entity is:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public int? ParentId {get; set;}
    public virtual Customer Parent {get; set;}
}
```

The Customer entity can have 0..1 related customer as Parent. After I add the navigation property and the association in the designer, and it generates the classes again, I get the following error:

> Running transformation: Multiplicity is not valid in Role 'Customer1' in relationship 'FK_customers_customers'. Because the Dependent Role properties are not the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be *.

I obviously don't want a 1..n relationship because then I have a collection of parents in my customer.

Is there a workaround?

Comment: Does that class compile? What is a `Customer?` customer is a class.

Comment: Typo. Should be just Customer. Also, the class is generated by the designer. I just copied it here for the question.

Comment: But I think you _do_ want / need a 0..n collection of 'children' from the perspective of the 'parent'

Comment: Did you thinking about using code-first approach? In this approach you can map 1->0..1 association without any problems. And code-first approach can be used with existing database.

Comment: I will soon start implementing CF but at the moment I need to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating a collection for the children? Like:

```
public virtual ICollection<Customer> Children { get; protected set; }
```

Comment: @BenRobinson there are potentially many children in the scenario of the OP -- when viewed from the parent perspective.

Comment: How does this answer the OP's question?